# A function that builds chessboard

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to answer the following problem from the book Eloquent Javascript.

"Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline
characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space
or a "#" character. The characters should form a chessboard.
Passing this string to console.log should show something like this:

```
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
```

When you have a program that generates this pattern, define a binding size
= 8 and change the program so that it works for any size, outputting a grid
of the given width and height." (pg.38, Marijin Haverbeke)

I have come up with the following code. I opted to use an X over spaces to represent the white tiles given it is easier to see.
I have come up with the following but the last loop that is supposed to add the new rows and \n isn't working. What is wrong?

```
function chessBoard (dimension) {
    for (let counter = 0; counter < dimension; counter++) {
        if (boardLine == "") {
            boardLine += "#";
            lastValue = hash;
            console.log(lastValue)
        } else if (lastValue == hash) {
            boardLine += "X";
            lastValue = space;
            console.log(lastValue)
        } else if (lastValue == space) {
            boardLine += "#";
            lastValue = hash;
            console.log(lastValue)
        } else {
          console.log("Error, something went wrong.");
        }
    }
    
    for (let counter2 = 0; counter2 < dimension; counter2++) {
        if (counter2/2 == 0) {
            boardLine += "\n";
            console.log(boardLine)
        } else if (counter2/2 !== 0) {
            boardLine = boardLine + " ";
        } else {
            console.log("Error. Somewhere around here.")
        }
    }
    }
    return boardLine;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra curly bracket before your `return`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this...

Short and easy :

Edit : I made the code more human readable. Apologies for the previous answer without proper explanation.

You can check the [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for a better understanding.

```js
function chessBoard (dimension) {
    if (!dimension) return "";

    let dimensionlengthArray = new Array(dimension).fill(null);

    // will return a string starting from X
    let line = dimensionlengthArray.map((v,i) => i%2===0?"X":"#").join("");

    // will return a string starting from #
    let reverseLine = [...line].reverse().join("");

    //returns a board starting from line and alternatively filling reverse line
    let board = dimensionlengthArray.map((v,i) => i%2===0?line:reverseLine).join("\n");

    return board;
}

console.log(chessBoard(8));
```

Comment: Don't aim for short and easy. Would you be able to comprehend the code after a week of not looking at it? Try to make your code more readable.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it more readable. Also apart from being short... This is more efficient.

Comment: You do not need to spread your `dimensionLengthArray` on creating `line` and `board`. Since `map` always returns a new array.`